# Determining Available Recruits in Java Game

Tags: java

I am making a Recruit Army System on my Java Text Based Strategy RPG, so here are the integers by the way:

```
    public int Swordsman; //Price: 10 each
public int Ronin; //Price: 10 each
public int Rider; //Price: 20 each
public int Archer; //Price: 10 each
public int Wizard; //Price: 20 each
public int Mage; //Prince: 20 each
public int Destroyer; //Price: 40 each
public int Soldiers; //Price: 30 each
public int totalarmies = Swordsman+Archer+Wizard+Mage+Destroyer+Soldiers;
```

So first off, I made some dialogues that will display the ones I will recruit:

```
                System.out.println("=========RECRUIT============");
            System.out.println("Coins: " + coins);
            System.out.println("Swordsman - 10 Coins Each");
            System.out.println("Ronin - 30 Coins Each");
            System.out.println("Rider - 20 Coins Each");
            System.out.println("Archer - 10 Coins Each");
            System.out.println("Wizard - 10 Coins Each");
            System.out.println("Mage - 20 Coins Each");
            System.out.println("Destroyer - 40 Coins Each");
            System.out.println("Soldier - 10 Coins Each");
            System.out.println("===========================");
```

Say for example I have the user input how many Swordsman he or she likes to recruit. I set up a Scanner to scan the number the user inputs and say the user inputs 20 (as max).

How can I determine the amount of coins needed to the number of the recruits the user inputs and if the coins I have on my pack can sustain the amount of recruits?

Second question is, how can I limit the user to recruit 20 units max to each class, so that the user can only recruit 20 swordsmen, 20 ronins etc?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a *very* rudimentary programming problem and probably off topic for the site.

> How can I determine the amount of coins needed to the number of the recruits the user inputs

coinsRequired = SwordsMen * *playerInputNumber*

> if the coins I have on my pack can sustain the amount of recruits

if( coins >= coinsRequired ) { ... }

> how can I limit the user to recruit 20 units max to each class

I'd just set up a dictionary of id (type of unit) to int (number of that unit) and keep track of the number of units that way.